# How to extract numbers from string and store as single integer?

Tags: c

Say I have a string like

> ab234cid*(s349*(20kd

and I want to extract all the numbers 234, 349, 20, and store it as a single integer value which would be **23434920** in this case?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service, please show your efforts

Comment: Please pick C or C++ or raise 2 questions. The answers will be very different.

Comment: 1) Loop over the string, pulling out digits into a new string. 2) convert the new string into an int.

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/XyAZwv)

Comment: Awesome thanks @BLUEPIXY

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Nice but I would use `if (isdigit(*str)) { ... }`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: I would recommend you to post that as an answer here as nobody else has posted an appropiate answer here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following algorithm:

- Initialise result to 0
- Iterate over characters of the string

  - If character is in the range `['0', '9']` then

    - Multiply the previous result with 10 (this is a decimal shift left)
    - Convert the character to the numeric value of the digit
    - Add the numeric value to the result

---

Bonus answer (I know OP removed [c++] tag): While the algorithm can be directly translated from natural language, it can be simplified in C++.

```
accumulate(begin(str), end(str), 0, [](int r, char c){
    return isdigit(c)
        ? r*10 + (c - '0')
        : r;
});
```

Comment: How about building a string of numbers and calling `sscanf` instead of multiplying and adding?

Comment: @babon If original string may be modified, then that is comparable. But if it is not, then you need unnecessary allocation for the copy that contains only the digits.

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned int IntegerFromString(unsigned char* str)
{
    unsigned int num = 0;

    for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i<strlen(str) ; i++){

        if(isdigit(str[i])){

            num *= 10;
            num += (str[i] - 48);
        } 
    }

    return num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that through iterating over the string scanning for digits then use one of conversion APIs:

```
string str = "ab234cid*(s349*(20kd";

string strNum;

for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
    while(isdigit(str[i])){
        strNum += str[i];
        int value = atoi(strNum.c_str());
        cout << "Value: " << value << endl;
        i++;
    }
    strNum = "";
}
```

- What I recommend is to use `regex`.

Comment: That won't work. OP has removed the [tag:c++] tag.

Comment: He can just use character string instead of `class string` then.

Comment: Sure, but you could also adapt the answer to that. There is more to change than just `std::string` to `char*` ...

Answer (score -1):

you can use std::stringstream for this.
for your first problem you can to it like this: (let text be the string containing "CAPACITY : 100")
1
2
3
4
5

```
std::string tmp;
int value;
char c;
std::stringstream ss(text);
ss >> tmp >> c >> value;
```

tmp will be CAPACITY, c will be : and value will be 100.
but this only works because capacity and : are seperated by a space. if they are not, you dont need the >> c part.

for your second problem: (let text be the string containing "1 82 76")
1
2
3
4
5

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
std::stringstream ss(text);
ss >> a >> b >> c;

a will be 1, b 82 and c 76
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, The OP has removed the C++ tag. Though I don't think this solution is general enough for their purpose.

Comment: But they might understand what they need to do...

Comment: Agreed I just wanted to make clear that you're now answering the wrong question.

Comment: thanks.... People edit it after submitting :D

Comment: I do feel a bit responsible because C & C++ makes zero sense in this question. The more I go on the more "C / C++" questions annoy me. There are fewer and fewer cases where the answers are the same.

Comment: Yes you are right.